# Unable to find distance between two coordinates by using ST_Distance in postgis and rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

I have a vendors model with the following schema

```
create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.decimal  "latitude",   precision: 9, scale: 6
t.decimal  "longitude",  precision: 9, scale: 6
t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
end
```

I populated the database with Faker gem and few hard coded values to get the longitude and latitude

I need to find the near by vendors within a particular given distance .I was able to achieve this with the following code in my vendor.rb

```
scope :close_to, -> (latitude, longitude, distance_in_meters = 2000) {
      where(%{
        ST_DWithin(
          ST_GeographyFromText(
            'SRID=4326;POINT(' || vendors.longitude || ' ' || 
            vendors.latitude || ')'
          ),
          ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
          %d
        )
      } % [longitude, latitude, distance_in_meters])
    }
```

So if I call

```
Vendor.close_to(39.000000, -76.000000, 500)
```

in my rails console I get four rows. Now I need to find the actual distance between each of these row co-ordinates and the mentioned co-ordinate in close_to scope.In order to achieve that I wrote the following code in vendor.rb

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :close_to, -> (latitude, longitude, distance_in_meters = 2000) {
      where(%{
        ST_DWithin(
          ST_GeographyFromText(
            'SRID=4326;POINT(' || vendors.longitude || ' ' || 
             vendors.latitude || ')'
          ),
          ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
          %d
        )
      } % [longitude, latitude, distance_in_meters])
    }

  scope :dist, -> { 
        where(%{
          ST_Distance(
              ST_GeographyFromText(
                'SRID=4326;POINT(' || vendors.longitude || ' ' || 
                 vendors.latitude || ')'
              ),
              ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-76.000000 
              39.000000)'),
            ) as distance;
        } % )
     }
end
```

however When I call

```
Vendor.close_to(39.000000, -76.000000).dist
```

It does not gives me the distance for the four rows and in fact throws a syntax error. I am a novice rails and postgres developer. I believe I have got the concept entirely wrong. Pleas help me rectify it, how do I find the nearby vendors from a given co-ordinates within a specific range as well as find the distance between each of these near by vendors from the given co-ordinates

Comment: Could you add the actual syntax error you get?

Comment: SyntaxError: /home/osboxes/office/refuelly/app/models/vendor.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: Try removing the `%` in the one line before the end (`} % )` should be `})`)

Comment: I tried what you suggested , but leads to this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" LINE 15:        ) as distance;
                ^

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, I would guess you have a parameter missing after `39.000000)'),`? a wild guess would be `500`?

Comment: or perhaps you want to delete that `,`?

Comment: Oh yes that was an error on my part.I overlooked it. However after removing that, it throws me this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type double precision
LINE 10:        ST_Distance(   ...... Can you help me fix the syntax proprly. I mean I am blindly trying everything because I don't what is the correct syntax or logic for that. Or else if you could another way for me to achieve the same , it would really helpful.

Comment: Again, I'm not even sure what you are trying to achieve... I would suggest, instead of blindly trying everything, or hope some stranger will do it for you - go and read the documentation, and try to understand what you need to do...